# Edit XML before comparing with another XML

Tags: c#, xml, string, split

I am comparing two XML Strings but want to delete some specific <strike>attribute</strike> element before comparing them.

I want to remove `<orderby>` <strike>attribute</strike> element and all data within these tags

XML 1:

```
<query>
<selecttables>
  <field>
    <tablerscd>1014</tablerscd>
    <tablename> OEM IHS Engines</tablename>
   </field>
   <orderby>
   </orderby>
</selecttables>
</query>
```

XML 2:

```
<query>
<selecttables>
   <field>
     <tablerscd>1014</tablerscd>
     <tablename> OEM IHS Engines</tablename>
   </field>
   <orderby>
      <columnrscd>1228</columnrscd>
      <columnrscd>1229</columnrscd>
   </orderby>
  </selecttables>
</query>
```

**My Question is:**

How can i remove `<orderby>` attribute and all data within these tags before I compare them.

Comment: Your xml is invalid. &lt;selecttables> does not have a closing tag.

Comment: @PhilB I copied specific portion and and xml validity is not the issue

Comment: `<orderby>` is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: Having invalid xml will significantly restrict your options and if this is truely not xml then you should remove xml references from the question.

Comment: @PhilB I have corrected the xml, now you will be able to answer my question ?

Comment: Sorry I'm using SO app on phone and doing full answer is a pain but if you search for "remove element c# linq-to-xml" on SO it should set you off in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [my own question about removing comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1874132/205233) you can do this:

```
// load your Xml string into an XDocument
var xml = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstringhere);

foreach (var node in xml.SelectNodes("//orderby").ToList())
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

Which will find all `orderby`elements, navigate to their parent element and delete them from there.

I adopted this answer from [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1874182/205233), who pointed out that it will be safer to create a `List` before removing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very trivially using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

doc.Descendants("orderby").Remove();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YbTkFM) for a demo.