# json.net using JsonConvert.SerializeObject adds a comment to output

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

How do I remove the comment at the bottom of created json string?

I am attempting to use Json.net to convert xml to json. Specifically, I am fetching data from the Zillow API which returns XML which I need to deliver to a web browser as a json string. Thanks to questions/answers found on this site, I have been able to use json.net in my c# page to maket the conversion, BUT...

I use the following to convert my xml to json:

```
public String GetJson(XmlDocument xml)
{
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xml);
}
```

I successfully get a json formatted String, but this comment is added at the bottom of the json (seems to be a timestamp).

```
{
... json-formatted output...
/* H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda */
}
```

I have checked the original xml to verify the comment is not there, so I have concluded it is added by json.net. I have searched this site - and Google - for info on this, but I am not finding the right search tokens to find any mention of this comment.

Thanks!

Comment: We need a [mcve] showing how you got the XML and what its string value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way that Json.NET will insert a hardcoded [comment](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteComment.htm) when serializing an `XmlDocument` -- there simply isn't any logic to do this in [`XmlNodeConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs).  The only time `XmlNodeConverter` will write a comment is if an XML node of type [`XmlNodeType.Comment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype(v=vs.110).aspx) was actually encountered in the XML DOM hierarchy, at around line [1502](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L1502) in the source code:

```
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                if (writePropertyName)
                {
                    writer.WriteComment(node.Value);
                }
                break;
```

Thus there are only a few ways such a comment string could have gotten added to your JSON output, including:

1. There might actually be [comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256201(v=vs.110).aspx) in your XML, added by the Zillow API or by your own app somewhere in its code stack.  For instance, given the following XML:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <root>
       <childNode>
           <innerChildNode>Some Text</innerChildNode>
       </childNode>
       <!-- H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  --> 
   </root>
   <!-- H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  -->
   ```

   Json.NET will generate the following JSON:

   ```
   {
     "?xml": {
       "@version": "1.0",
       "@encoding": "utf-8"
     },
     "root": {
       "childNode": {
         "innerChildNode": "Some Text"
       }/* H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  */
     }/* H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  */
   }
   ```
2. Somewhere in your code stack, your app might have installed its own version of `XmlNodeConverter` in [`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm) that inserts comments into the output.  For instance, given the following global converter:

   ```
   JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       Converters = { new FixedXmlNodeConverter() },
   };

   public class FixedXmlNodeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter
   {
       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
           writer.WriteComment("Global Comment: H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda");
       }
   }
   ```

   The JSON generated will contain extra comments:

   ```
   {
     "?xml": {
       "@version": "1.0",
       "@encoding": "utf-8"
     },
     "root": {
       "childNode": {
         "innerChildNode": "Some Text"
       }/* H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  */
     }/* H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda  */
   }/*Global Comment: H:011  T:134ms  S:1206  R:Tue May 02 07:59:03 PDT 2017  B:5.0.42642-master.3acb9f9~hotfix_pre.b72ccda*/
   ```
3. You might be using your own custom build of Json.NET with a customized version of `XmlNodeConverter`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cL6Pz5) demonstrating the first two possibilities.

If you actually have comment nodes in your XML, you can strip them by following one of the suggestions in [How to remove all comment tags from XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1874132/3744182) or any number of similar questions.   If you have a global converter installed, you can supersede it by manually allocating an `XmlNodeConverter` and passing it to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.

To handle these two cases, your `GetJson()` might become:

```
    public String GetJson(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        XmlNodeList list = xml.SelectNodes("//comment()");
        foreach(XmlNode node in list)
        {
            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
        }

        var converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.XmlNodeConverter();
        // Use Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None in your production code
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, converter);
    }
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fBqZeo).

If you are using your own custom build of Json.NET, you would need to investigate and fix why this is happening.

If for whatever reason you cannot modify the incoming `XmlDocument` (or cannot fix your custom build of Json.NET) you could subclass [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) and override [`WriteComment`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WriteComment.htm) (and possibly [`WriteCommentAsync`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WriteCommentAsync.htm) though that's not needed here) and make them do nothing:

```
public class NoCommentJsonTextWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public NoCommentJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer)
        : base(writer)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteComment(string text)
    {
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
    public String GetJson(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
        // Use Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None in your production code
        using (var writer = new NoCommentJsonTextWriter(textWriter) { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented })
        {
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Serialize(writer, xml);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0e3oIP).

Comment: It was item 1; the comment was in the xml, but was not in the same spot in the json (at least as I viewed the xml in a console window.) Thanks for the thorough answer, @dbc, you actually helped me with another issue with this description.